# How leaving a menu that accompanies the scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

How do I leave a set menu according to the scroll?

I did a snippet to illustrate the code. I open the menu when I scroll the page he is in his position. I want the menu to track scrolling the page.

How can I do this?

```js
  var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
  var showMenu = document.getElementById("abrir");
  var hideMenu = document.getElementById("fechar");
  showMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.add("show");
  });

  hideMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.remove("show");
  });
```

```css
 html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 } 

 #site{  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
 }

 #fundo_site{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 #menu{
  position: absolute;
  left: -292px;
  height:100%;
  width:15%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
 }

 #img_menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 #menu.show{
  left:0;
 }

 #bt_menu{
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  margin: 15px;
 }


 p{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;   
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -5px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Meu Site</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
 

</head>
<body>
 

 <div id="site">
   <img id="fundo_site" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINau.jpg.jpg">
   <a id="abrir" style="position:absolute;"> <img id="bt_menu" src="img/bt.png"></a>
 </div>
 


  <div id="menu">  
  <p id="fechar" style="position:absolute;"><strong>X</strong></p>
  <img id="img_menu" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiAvt.jpg.jpg">
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first step is picking up some web development and programming terms, Zkk. I, for one, don't have a clue what you are asking, after reading your question twice. And I'm generally regarded as a seasoned full-stack developer.

Comment: Open the side menu and scroll down the page! You will see see the MENU remain at the top of the page. I want, when you scroll the page, the menu down together! I want the menu accompanies the scroll the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to have the menu fixed in a position so it is always visible even when you scroll, what you have to do is change its position from `absolute` to `fixed` and that will do the trick:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
  var showMenu = document.getElementById("abrir");
  var hideMenu = document.getElementById("fechar");
  showMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.add("show");
  });

  hideMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.remove("show");
  });
```

```css
html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 } 

 #site{  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
 }

 #fundo_site{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 #menu{
        /* LINE CHANGED */
  position: fixed;
  left: -292px;
  height:100%;
  width:15%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
 }

 #img_menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 #menu.show{
  left:0;
 }

 #bt_menu{
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  margin: 15px;
 }


 p{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;   
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -5px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Meu Site</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
 

</head>
<body>
 

 <div id="site">
   <img id="fundo_site" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINau.jpg.jpg">
   <a id="abrir" style="position:absolute;"> <img id="bt_menu" src="img/bt.png"></a>
 </div>
 


  <div id="menu">  
  <p id="fechar" style="position:absolute;"><strong>X</strong></p>
  <img id="img_menu" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiAvt.jpg.jpg">
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $("#menu").removeClass("show");  
  
});
```